# Process.waitFor() a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, process, processbuilder, inputstreamreader

While running an external script, I want to read the ErrorStream and OutputStream of this script both simultaneously and separately and then process them further. Therefore, I start a `Thread` for one of the streams. Unfortunately, the `Process` doesn't seem to `waitFor` the `Thread` to be terminated, but return after the non-threaded stream has no further input.

In a nutshell, here is what I am doing:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(script);  
final Process p = pb.start();  

new Thread(new Runnable() {  
  public void run() {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    ...read lines and process them...
  }
}).start();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
...read lines and process them...

int exitValue = p.waitFor();
p.getOutputStream().close();
return exitValue;
```

Is there any possibility to `waitFor` the `Thread` to be terminated?

Comment: Maybe just use [Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec//) - no use reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Would be helpful if you posted your real code. Two things, you never start your input stream reader thread; and you should not close the processes output stream before it is complete.

Comment: @Perception : Sorry for the incomplete and thus defective code. I have corrected it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use `Thread.join(...)` to wait for a `Thread` to finish.  Note that the call throws `InterruptedException` if the current thread receives an interrupt before the thread you are waiting for finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's general code for doing what you want to do. In this case there is both input and output: I am piping `someFile` into the process and piping the output to `System.out`. `Files.copy()` and `ByteStreams.copy()` are just Guava convenience methods to hook up an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream`. We then wait for the command to finish.

```
final Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try (OutputStream stdin = pr.getOutputStream()) {
            Files.copy(someFile, stdin);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}.start();

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try (InputStream stdout = pr.getInputStream()) {
            ByteStreams.copy(stdout, System.out);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }  
    }
}.start();              

int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
if( exitVal == 0 )
    System.out.println("Command succeeded!");
else    
    System.out.println("Exited with error code " + exitVal);
```

A more verbose version if you are running prior to Java 7 with the *try-with-resources* block:

```
final Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        OutputStream stdin = null;
        try {
            Files.copy(someFile, stdin = pr.getOutputStream());
        } 
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        finally {
            if( stdin != null ) {
                try { stdin.close(); } 
                catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }               
    }
}.start();

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        InputStream stdout = null;
        try {
            ByteStreams.copy(stdout = pr.getInputStream(), System.out);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        finally {
            if( stdout != null ) {
                try { stdout.close(); } 
                catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }               
    }
}.start();              

int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
if( exitVal == 0 )
    System.out.println("Command succeeded!");
else    
    System.out.println("Exited with error code " + exitVal);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, using 'Commons Exec' doesn't work for me. There is no `waitFor` the threaded stream, as well. But I could solve the problem using Stephan's solution above.

Comment: Not sure where you see Commons Exec in my answer. The `Process` and its `waitFor()` method are available in standard Java.

Comment: Very useful answer (first code) but I had to use "IOUtils" instead of "ByteStreams" (second thread).

Comment: Hello Andrew, do you think it is required to close the process stream (variable stdout) ? Once the process exits , the streams would be closed automatically, isnt it? Not sure, so asking you.

Comment: You don't have to if this is the only code running in the process, but it's generally good practice to because if you do this along with some other code, it will cause a memory leak.